# User Name in version history

Tags: cme

We have developed a custom page which shows the list of items checked out. Non admin users (part of a business group) are authorized to use this custom page.

These users are non admins and through this custom page, we have given them check in and undo checkout options by invoking a core service client with service account credentials.

The problem is, whenever a user comes and executes check in, it is creating a version with the actual user who checked out the item rather than the user who forced the check in. Is there a way to show the user who actually forced the check in other than the service account or actual checked out user?

Answer (score 5):

You could record the actual user in application data. Then you would need a GUI extension to display it.

So it's possible, but I wonder how much value it has. Forced check-ins should be a pretty rare occurrence (or there's something wrong with the way people are working).

Answer (score 4):

You need Administrator rights to force a check-in or undo check-out, and you are elevating the rights of these non admins by giving them access to a core service application. So you can NEVER expect to get their original user name in any of your actions (you are bypassing that name yourself).

With regards to what shows up in the history, the forced check-in by an Administrator will perform an action that it expected the user to do itself. The change was made by a user, but the change was never checked in, by forcing the check-in, the history of the item will not show who performed the check-in, it registers the user who made the modification (the one that initially checked out the item).

If the user making the edit actually never saved a minor version, the force check-in will not even retain any real changes, but just clear the lock from the item for other edits. This is similar to a undo check-out. But the latter actually doesn't have any record in the version history, since no change was made to the item (it was undone, and there are no minor versions in the history kept after check-in).